# How to read json file and print ,in php

Tags: php, json

below data in .json file. i want read and print the data.

```
{" employees" :[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName": "Jones"}
]};
```

Comment: is `var employees` is a part of your .json file  ???

Comment: That's not JSON, that's JavaScript

Comment: so you just try to confuse us as much as possible? :-) `below data in .json file.`

Answer (score 2):

**Your json file** `("/something/abc.json")`

```
{"employees":[
    {
        "firstName":"Ray",
        "lastName":"Villalobos",
        "joined":2012
    },
    {
        "firstName":"John",
        "lastName":"Jones",
        "joined":2010
    }
]}
```

**Your php code,**

```
<?php
$string = file_get_contents("/something/abc.json");
$arr = json_decode($string,true);

foreach($arr as $a)
{
    // Iteration
}
?>
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON, you need `[]` around your file

Comment: You are right! Thanks, made changes :)